# how do i reverse the order when echoing my results?

Tags: php

i have this bit of code:

```
<?php   
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
preg_match_all("/<a href=(.*?links.*?)>.*?<\/a>/i", $file, $a);
$count = count($a[1]);
for ($row = 0; $row < $count ; $row++) {
$linkurls = $a[1]["$row"];
echo ' '.$linkurls.' <br>';
}
?>
```

and currently it echos the links in order they appear on the website. I would like for it to echo the results in a reverse order (the last link on example.com to echo as the first with this code)

any help is appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($row = $count - 1; $row > -1 ; $row--) {
    $linkurls = $a[1]["$row"];
    echo ' '.$linkurls.' <br>';
}
```

Comment: @Alin Nothing really, just happened to be the first thing I typed - both work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function for it: [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

```
$a[1] = array_reverse($a[1]);
```

Also why would you use `["$row"]` instead of `[$row]`? There is no functional difference as numeric strings get converted back to numbers when using them as indexes, so don't worry about that, but just because something can be done doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: ive actually tried that and arsort and rsort with $a and $linkurls doesnt seem to work. unless im doing somethign wrong.

Comment: @user575594 Try reversing `$a[1]`, not `$a`. And use just `array_reverse`, don't use sorting functions. Also it looks to me that you would still benefit from some [PHP basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
preg_match_all("/<a href=(.*?links.*?)>.*?<\/a>/i", $file, $a);
$a = array_reverse($a);
$count = count($a[1]);
for ($row = 0; $row < $count ; $row++) {
$linkurls = $a[1]["$row"];
echo ' '.$linkurls.' <br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: ive tried, the code still works, but echos result in the exact same order

Comment: `$a[1] = array_reverse($a[1]);`